# Graphic card does not perform well when I plug in my AC adapter. However, it does on the Battery mode

Tags: windows-10, laptop, performance, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I am working on an Artificial Intelligence project by training my Neural Network model on my Alienware laptop.

**Configuration:**
Type: Alienware 17r3

Screen resolution: 4k

GPU: GTX 980M

CPU: i7-6820HK

RAM: 32 Go

Disk: 1 To SSD and 1 To HDD.

Windows 10

**Problem description:**

When I work on battery mode, the training process (using the GPU) works fine (example: the loss decreases from 7.91 until 7.83 which is the same when I try it on desktop). At the moment of Plugging-in the AC adapter, the training process starts computing randomly (example: the loss starts from 7.74, goes up to 15.61 and it keeps rising fastly).
I have tried the same code in another machine, with GTX1060, it performs well (the loss decreases from 7.91 until 5.45 after several iterations).
While in gaming, it performs well in plugging-in, no error occurred.

**Solutions that I have tried:**

Option 1: I have reinstalled many driver versions of the GTX 980M GPU and even the Cuda versions, and none works while plug-in. (but when using the battery, the computer performs well).

Option 2: I have changed the -Power Options mode- to "balanced" for the plug-in similarly to the battery one. I still face the same problem.
Kindly suggest a solution for my issue as I am in need of help.

Note: I have recorded this problem. You may find a video of it on Youtube: https://youtu.be/6O-ymO8Rrq0

Comment: Odd problem indeed, change Power Options to high performance and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have changed it to the High-performance option, the issue still the same.